# UTF-7 on website?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

We are in the process of converting our Windows-1252 based webshop to Unicode. Unfortunately we currently have to use a middleware between the shop and the ERP which cannot handle UTF-8 (it will corrupt the characters).

We could use UTF-7 for passing the content through the middleware but I'd like to avoid having to convert all data before it enters and exits the middleware.

This is why I thought of using UTF-7 alltogehter. Is there a technical reason not to use UTF-7 on your website?

Comment: You have a middleware which handles UTF-7 and corrupts UTF-8 ?

Comment: @dystroy Well the middleware does not exactly handle UTF-7 but at least it does not corrupt the text since special characters are encoded using ASCII only (or at least I did not yet see any corruptions)

Comment: What middleware are you using? (Sounds like you need to find something better.)

Comment: @KeithThompson yes I think so, too. Unfortunately we cannot change both at once and moreover management doesn't want to change the middleware if it isn't broken (even more). It's not a commonly known component I guess maybe a couple installations top

Comment: @ooxi: And you don't want to identify it? It might be helpful information for others.

Comment: @KeithThompson I really doubt the identification of the middleware  would be helpful for anybody since the software was programmed by some cowboy coder and sold to a couple of local businesses. It's not something you would find in the wild. Nethertheless I fear disclosing the information would degrade the relationship to the author of the middleware who is the only person which can support it :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[HTML5 forbids the support of UTF-7 by browsers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#character0)  :

> Furthermore, authors must not use the CESU-8, UTF-7, BOCU-1 and SCSU
>   encodings, which also fall into this category; these encodings were
>   never intended for use for Web content.

...

> User agents must support the encodings defined in the WHATWG Encoding
>   standard. User agents should not support other encodings.
>
> User agents must not support the CESU-8, UTF-7, BOCU-1 and SCSU
>   encodings. [CESU8] [UTF7] [BOCU1] [SCSU]

An extract from [the list of character encodings supported by Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko/Character_sets_supported_by_Gecko?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Character_Sets_Supported_by_Gecko) :

> UTF-7 Obsolete since Gecko 5.0    Unicode *Support removed for HTML5 compatibility*.

**Don't use UTF-7.**

BTW having a middleware which supports UTF-7 but not UTF-8 looks strange. Maybe this middleware can handle the files as binary ? In any case your middleware might be a little too old to be in use now.

Comment: Thanks that's a bold argument for not using UTF-7! The middleware isn't that old but really bad. I'll have to look at another approach, maybe forcing HTML entities everywhere :(

Answer (score 4):

Current versions of Chrome, Firefox, and IE do not support UTF-7 at all (they render an UTF-7 encoded HTML document by displaying its source code as such, since they do not recognize any tags). This is a sufficient reason for not even considering the use of UTF-7 on the web.